# Removing Prefix from column of names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset

```
ID      Name     
101    DR. ADAM SMITH
102    BEN DAVIS
103    MRS. ASHELY JOHNSON
104    DR. CATHY JONES 
105    JOHN DOE SMITH
```

Desired Output

```
ID        Name 
101     ADAM SMITH
102     BEN DAVIS
103     ASHELY JOHNSON
104     CATHY JONES
105     JOHN DOE SMITH
```

I need to get rid of the prefix I tried `df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(to_replace = 'DR. ', value = '')`I repeated the same code for all prefixes, but I have when I do it nothing happens. Any reason for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a regular expression to remove a word that ends with `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the first word if it ends with `.`.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'^[A-Z]+\.\s+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: I'm no regex expert, but will this work if the string is lowercase?

Comment: No, it won't, but the examples are all uppercase. You can use `case=False` to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

'''
# Sample data
data = {
'ID': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
'Name': ['DR. ADAM SMITH', 'BEN DAVIS', 'MRS. ASHELY JOHNSON', 'DR. CATHY JONES', 'JOHN DOE SMITH']
}

```
# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to remove prefixes from names
def remove_prefix(name):
    prefixes = ['DR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MS.']  # Add more prefixes if needed
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if name.startswith(prefix):
            return name[len(prefix)+1:]
    return name

# Apply the function to the 'Name' column
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(remove_prefix)

# Print the modified DataFrame
print(df)
```

'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use use regular expression to replace the part of string. For example:

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'^(?:DR|MRS?)\.\s*', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID            Name
0  101      ADAM SMITH
1  102       BEN DAVIS
2  103  ASHELY JOHNSON
3  104     CATHY JONES
4  105  JOHN DOE SMITH
```

---

Note: `.replace(r'DR. ', '')` is trying to replace the whole `DR.`  with empty string, not only the part of string.

Comment: What if a string was "MR. JOHN SMITH"?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy That's why I added the `?` in the regex. It will match `DR`, `MR` and `MRS`

Answer (score 0):

**Use a Regular Expression:**

```
import re

name = "DR. ADAM SMITH"
print(re.sub(r".*\.\s", "", name)) # ADAM SMITH
```

This expression matches anything that ends with a period and a space, and should match most prefixes ("DR.", "MRS.", "MR.", etc). You can integrate it into your code like this:

1. Add the line `import re` at the top of your code.
2. Use the line `df['Name'] = re.sub(r".*\.\s", "", df['Name'])` instead of `df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(to_replace = 'DR. ', value = '')`

For more on regular expressions see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. You needed to add .str:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('DR. ', '')
```

Comment: This won't replace `"MRS."`, like the OP wanted.

Answer (score -1):

The reason nothing happens when you use the `replace()` function is because it treats the input as a literal string and looks for an exact match.

In your case, the values in the 'Name' column contain additional spaces before and after the prefixes, so the exact match is not found.

To overcome this issue, you can use regular expressions (regex) from the `re` module to remove the prefixes from the 'Name' column:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'Name': ['DR. ADAM SMITH', 'BEN DAVIS', 'MRS. ASHELY JOHNSON', 'DR. CATHY JONES', 'JOHN DOE SMITH']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b(?:DR\.|MRS\.)\s*', '', x))

print(df)
```